# Query to return rows with all columns equal except the key

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with some rows that are duplicates of others in all but the key column. I need to return a list of all the key values that have duplicates. For example:

```
(key)
ID       Column_B Column_C Column_D Column_E
1        foo      bar      beyond   belief       
2        foo      bar      beyond   belief  
3        blah     blah2    blah3    blah4       
4        ho       hum      di       dum       
5        foo      bar      beyond   belief
```

In this case, I need the query to return `1, 2, and 5` as these keys all have duplicate values in all of their other columns..

I can do this easily enough in this simplified example using a join like this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN (SELECT Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, Column_E
            FROM mytable
            GROUP BY Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, Column_E
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2
ON t.Column_B = t2.Column_B
AND t.Column_C = t2Column_C
AND t.Column_D = t2.Column_D
AND t.Column_E = t2.Column_E
```

But my 'real' table has a lot of columns (20+) and this could grow (its a denormalised table for quick report generation), so I was hoping someone could come up with either:

- something a bit more dynamic, or
- something slightly less unwieldy than joining on all columns.

SQL or PL/SQL are both ok..

Comment: The only way to do this is with DynamicSQL.  Is that a route you really want to go down?

Comment: @Dems: I could write some dynamic SQL, but I'd rather not. Was hoping there was some other way, or at least a simpler way to write the static SQL above..

Comment: Why is `5` included or why is `3` not included?

Comment: @Lieven: Because the values in columns b, c, d and e for row 3 aren't duplicated on any other row. The values in row 5 match rows 1 and 2..

Comment: @StevieG - Got it... perhaps you might change `Column_A` to `ID` and change the numbers in `Columns_B_E` to something *other* than the values in `Column_A`... for other thick people like me <g>

Answer (score 1):

On oracle I would try something like this:

```
select column_a
     , t1.column_b || t1.column_c ... concat_value
from   my_table t1
where  t1.column_b || t1.column_c ... in 
       ( select t2.column_b || t2.column_c ... inner_concat_value
         from   mytable t2
         group by t2.column_a || t2.column_b ...
         having count(*) > 1
       )
```

I did not run this query but maybe it gives you an idea. Please think about a separator between fields, otherwise the results may not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have stragg (or a similar function), try this:

```
select stragg(to_char(ColumnA))
from my_table
group by Column_B, Column_C, Column_D, Column_E
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use dynamic SQL and you don't want to join on all columns, both of which I sort of agree with then the best thing is to hash all the other columns bar the primary key on entry into the table and then join solely on that; there is a absolutely miniscule change that you'll get a duplicate though. Something like the following should work:

```
function checksum( P_Str in varchar2 ) return varchar2 is

   l_CSum dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.raw_checksum;

begin

   if P_Str is null then
      return null;
   else
      dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5( input => utl_raw.cast_to_raw(P_Str)
                                  , checksum => l_CSum );
      return l_CSum;
   end if;

end checksum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select them in column order, putting the key as the last column.

Sort it so the duplicates end up next to each other.

Use LAG, to examine adjecent rows in the result set,
pulling off the keys and save them to a table.

Report the DISTINCT results of that table.